# Fortune Merrit Mental Poker for dummies (with TTP)

Tags: php, poker

It seems that the book writers have quite a talent at making a relatively simple concept incredibly complex to understand.

Could someone perhaps explain how fortune merrit works using pseudo code, PHP or perhaps relay it using other simple means? It would be greatly appreciated. SHA256 can be used as the hashing function for examples sake.

[image]

Comment: I'm extremely curious about what this is. Could you drop some more hints?

Comment: Shuffling poker cards in a provably fair manner